# Wait for signal

Tags: bash, shell-script, signals, trap

In a `bash` script, is there a simple way to wait for a signal, something like:

```
wait -s SIGINT
```

or whatever? Maybe just `trap`?

Comment: If you could explain a bit about what your specific use case is, I could possibly give a better answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.

`wait` is exclusively used in a parent process to wait for the termination of a child process (and to access its exit status).

Furthermore, no process may trap the `KILL` signal (the original question used `KILL` as example).

Also, to "wait for a signal" is an unusual thing to want to do, as signals are asynchronous events, meaning you don't *wait* for them, but instead you install a signal handler (using `trap` in the shell) that would handle the signal *whenever* it arrives.  A signal could be arriving at any time during the script's execution, and the signal handler would be executed when that happens (the normal program flow would temporarily pause while the signal is being handled).

You could, obviously, do something like

```
trap 'quit=1' USR1

quit=0
while [ "$quit" -ne 1 ]; do
    printf 'Do "kill -USR1 %d" to exit this loop after the sleep\n' "$$"
    sleep 1
done

echo The USR1 signal has now been caught and handled
```

to do a sort of a "waiting for signal to arrive" loop.

Here, the "trap" would "catch" the `USR1` signal, the "handler" would set `quit` to `1`, and control would be returned to the code, which would exit the loop.

Comment: huh? you `wait` for background child processes to die, and those are async events. what would be so different about waiting for an async signal?

Comment: i am def looking to do this without polling / timeout, if possible

Comment: i didnt mean just KILL by the way, I meant to include SIGTERM and SIGINT, sorry if that was confusing. I updated the question to make it better, I made a mistake by using KILL/SIGKILL instead of SIGINT, etc.

Comment: @AlexanderMills `wait` is a synchronization point in the program allowing the parent to wait for the child/children to finish their processing. Signals are exceptional events, occuring at any point in the program's life cycle.  Again, if you could explain in your question what kind of use case you have, a better explanation could be written.

Comment: The system call of interest here would be `pause`, not `wait`. As far as I am aware, there is no shell command to invoke the `pause` system call.